# perl - how to create an array with n empty strings or zeros?

Tags: perl

When I manipulate CSV files in Perl I often have a need to initialize an array with some number of same elements:

```
my $arr = [];
for my $i (0..$n-1) {
    push @$arr, "";
}
```

Is there a way to do it in a more compact form?

Perfectly I would like to have an expression for this purpose, so that I can add missing columns easily:

```
f([@$some_tab, n_elems("", $column_number - scalar(@$some_tab))]);
```

I know how to write a function, but I never do it in 10-line scripts.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the multiplier.

```
my @arr = ("") x $n;
```

Update: note that this duplicates the element, which might not be desirable if you are filling the array with references. In such a case, where each element needs to be constructed, you could use a `map`:

```
my @arr = map { [] } 1..$n;
```