# One-line creation of a perl array reference to an array of n empty strings

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I am initializing several parameters that are passed as optional key-value combinations to a subroutine:

```
my %options = (
    center       => 1, 
    caption      => '', 
    tablecss     => '', 
    captioncss   => '', 
    datacss      => '',
    headercss    => '', 
    allcellcss   => '', 
    texalignment => '', 
    midrules     => 0, 
    columnscss   => \(('') x $numcol),
    @_,
);
```

My problem is with the `columnscss` key. What I have in the above is leaving `$options{columnscss}` as a string reference, not an array reference. How can I initialize that key's value to be `['','',...,'']` with `$numcol` empty strings? I would like to avoid first creating the `array ('') x $numcol` in a separate line, and then assigning the key value as a reference to it. I believe that is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323845/perl-how-to-create-an-array-with-n-empty-strings-or-zeros) would have me do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an anonymous array:

```
columnscss => [ ('') x $numcol ]
```

The backslash operator is distributed, i.e. `\( $x, $y)` is the same as `(\$x, \$y)`.

Comment: And thanks also for the explanation how it was working out to be a string reference. That was a mystery to me.